# Maven TestNG surefire plugin run groups via terminal

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

Im currently working on trying to get the maven command line to run a certain group. I have annotated my tests as follows:

```
@Test(priority = 2, groups = "MyGroup")
public void myFirstTest(){};
```

then I I kick off the test run via command line like this:

```
mvn clean install test -Dgroups=MyGroup
```

Aaaaannnndddd nothing runs. Maven starts up, then quits saying there are no tests. Like so:

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 38.071 sec - in TestSuite
```

Now I tried a few things. 1st. I tried putting a testng.xml file and adding the group name "MyGroup" to the file. I then reference this file inside my pom.xml as such:

```
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- command to run "mvn clean test -DsuiteFile=src/test/resources/testng.xml" -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
```

When i the re-run using the command line it works. Now i know we dont need to add an xml file specifying the group names. As this is made dynamically by maven, so then what am I missing.

Also, i put a breakpoint in the method overridden transformer

```
    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
```

And annotation.getGroups() is always an empty array. This means that maven is not passing in the test groups. Why!!!. I really dont see it and been hacking away at this for hours, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `mvn clean install test..` calling Maven like this does not make sense, cause the life cycle `install` will  run the `test` already...running the `test` life cycle phase will run other phase an other time..See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: well it didnt make a difference in the outcome of the test. mvn test -Dgroups=MyGroup gave me the same output.